# Running 32 bit apps in WinPE 3 (Win7) 64 bit

Tags: wow64, winpe

Trying to run any 32 bit app in the WinPE 3.0 (Win7) 64 bit environment will result in the following error message:

`The subsystem needed to support the image type is not present.`

The missing subsystem in question is Windows on Windows 64 (WOW64): the compatibility layer allowing 32 bit apps to run in the 64 bit OS.

The question is: would it be possible to install WOW64 in WinPE? If so, how, and how big is the set of files to be installed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this doens't really resolve your problem but it is a work around for us.

We deploy Windows 7 64bit in 2 steps.

Step 1. Install Windows 7 64bit RTM using WinPE 3.0 64bit and install all MS Patches then Capture WIM.
Step 2. Deploy Captured Win7 64bit WIM using WinPE 3.0 32bit with 32bit apps running in WinPE.

This works like a charm. I don't know why but it does :)

So I think if you want to deploy from the RTM you might be stuck but there is no reason you can't just deploy RTM and then recapture it then use the 32bit WinPE.

Good luck!